# How to perform ng-show in the another tab?

Tags: angularjs

How to show validation errors on the second tab?
I'm learning angularJS validation, and here is the situation:
I create a big form with different input tags for all situation, it could be input, select, checkboxes. And I validate it with ng-show, for example:

```
<form name="MyForm">
  <label>My Name:</label>
      <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" ng-model="value" required>
      <span ng-show="MyForm.name.$error.required">This field is required</span>
...
```

So when the field is empty it says to me that it's required.

But I output all information from this form to the second tab (with is made with ui-router views):
First tab gets information from my form and put it to the the LocalStorage, than I go to the second tab and use ng-repeat to show all information from the LocalStorage. 
But how to say if some fields are empty on the second tab?
How to bind this two tabs, should I use ng-show, or there is another solution?

The result should be:

tab1:

```
<form name="MyForm">
<input name="name" required>   // input Mick
<input name="Last Name" required>  // leave empty
```

tab2:

- name:     Mick
- Last Name: This field is required

Sorry form my english, I how that everything is clear

Please se the link:  http://embed.plnkr.co/RlbB49J6LlTrMiHEcSZQ/preview

Comment: its kind of difficult for me to understand your issue, could you add a plunker or jsfiddle so we could look and help?

Comment: @Jony-Y   Please see http://embed.plnkr.co/RlbB49J6LlTrMiHEcSZQ/preview
I couldn't do store in LocalStorage in planker, but in my version data watches by $watch and then stores in LocalStorage, and after that I present it in the second tab. But if the field is empty I want there will be a ng-show "Field is required"  as in the first tab.

Comment: something like this? http://plnkr.co/edit/RhxschWGdy8tOEPSXPwS?p=preview

Comment: @Jony-Y Ou my God! I was so easy. I guess I need a little rest :) Yes, that's it. Thanks a lot